# how to take team total for unilevel mlm tree

Tags: mysql, tree, treeview, mlm

I need to find the team total for the unilevel mlm tree
I am having users table as this

```
+-------+-------+-----------+
| id    | fname | parent_id |
+=======+=======+===========+
| sk001 | aa    | null      |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk002 | ss    | ssk001    |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk003 | dd    | sk001     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk004 | ff    | sk002     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk005 | gg    | sk002     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk006 | hh    | sk005     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk007 | jj    | sk006     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk008 | kk    | sk006     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk009 | ll    | sk004     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
| sk010 | mm    | sk005     |
+-------+-------+-----------+
```

and I have invoice_order table like this

```
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| id    | fname | parent_id | amount |
+=======+=======+===========+========+
| sk001 | aa    | null      | 100    |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk002 | ss    | ssk001    | 400    |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk002 | dd    | sk001     | 225    |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk004 | ff    | sk002     | 50     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk005 | gg    | sk002     | 59     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk006 | hh    | sk005     | 77     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk007 | jj    | sk006     | 89     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk004 | ff    | sk002     | 87     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk009 | ll    | sk004     | 45     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| sk010 | mm    | sk005     | 56     |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
```

Here I have to calculate the personal total and the team total of the Ids,
example(tree):

```
             sk001 
                |
                |--sk002
                |     |--sk004
                |     |    |--sk009
                |     |    |--xy
                |     |
                |     |--sk005
                |
                |--sk003
```

for example : Team total of `sk002` should contain the total purchase amount of an individual in the team `(sk004,sk009,xy)`

I have just tries something like this :

```
SELECT  (SUM(amount))/2 as indteamtotal 
                                          from    (SELECT * from invoice_order
                                                   order by id, parent_id) products_sorted,
                                                  (SELECT @pv := 'sk002') initialisation
                                          where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) > 0
                                          and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)) order by parent_id asc
```

but I am not getting correct team total
Is there any possibilities to use mysql procedure

Comment: Why is this tagged `php`? There is no PHP in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE if you have MySQL 8+

```
with recursive tree as (
 select id from invoice_order where id = 'sk002'
 union
 select i.id from invoice_order i join tree on tree.id = i.parent_id
)  
select sum(amount) from invoice_order where id in (select id from tree);
```

Link to the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xjXzkQtGRNC7PwPBn6pq2e/0)

Comment: for  mysql 5+ What can i do @MBeale